# Contour Integration with Sympy Vector: Discrepancy in Result

Tags: python, vector, sympy, calculation

I'm attempting a contour integration using sympy's vector module, but the result differs significantly from my expectations.

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, ParametricRegion, ParametricIntegral
from sympy import symbols, pi, integrate, cos, sin
from sympy.geometry import Point, Curve, Ellipse, Segment, Polygon
from sympy.abc import t
C = CoordSys3D('C')
P = C.create_new('P', transformation='cylindrical')

def circle_integral(V, radius):
    curve = ParametricRegion((radius, t, 0),(t, 0, 2*pi))
    result = ParametricIntegral(V, curve)
    return result

H = symbols('H') #constant
V = H * P.j # vector with only rotation element phi
radius = symbols('Rin')
result = circle_integral(V, radius)
print(result)
```

The result is `2*pi*H`, whereas the expected result should be `2*pi*H*R`. I'm unsure how to define the curve so that the integral uses the correct Jacobian for cylindrical coordinates.

I know that for cylindrical coordinates, the path element is represented as:
[image]

and

[image]